# Annotation for method, which must work before a group of features (Cucumber + Junit)

Tags: junit, cucumber

Cucumber supports hooks -- methods that run before or after a scenario.
The @Before and @After annotations are used to mark them.
A method with @Before annotation will run before each scenario, @After -- after each scenario.
An example of a class with hooks:

```
public class Hooks {

  @Before
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("before each Cucumber scenario");
  }

  @After
  public void stop() {
    System.out.println("after each Cucumber scenario");
  }
}
```

Can you tell me, please, what annotations I must use in order to run method 1 time before the entire group of Cucumber-scenarios (feature-files)?

If there is no such annotation, then how can we do it in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard Junit annotation @BeforeAll and @AfterAll

@BeforeAll methods are only executed once for a given test class.
@BeforeAll is used to signal that the annotated method should be executed before all tests in the current test class.

Please refer this documentation [@BeforeAll](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html)